# Copy filenames with matching foldernames in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a bunch of filenames in a source drive i.e. G:\Langpacks that I need to copy to a destination drive i.e. G:\OSLANGS

The Source drive contains part of the destination directory name i.e.

1. G:\Langpacks\Microsoft-Windows-Client-Language-Pack_x64_de-de.cab
2. G:\Langpacks\Microsoft-Windows-Client-Language-Pack_x64_en-US.cab

The destination Drive folder name contains part of the filename i.e.

1. G:\OSLANGS\de-de
2. G:\OSLANGS\en-US

How do I copy matching file names from source to destination?
So far I have tried the below code but cant hardcode variables for each folder name, please help

````
$filename = '*de-de*.*' 
$searchinfolder = "G:\langpacks" Get-ChildItem -Path $searchinfolder -Filter $filename -Recurse | %{$_.FullName}  ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by iterating through the source folder and find all files with a .cab extension.
Then, add a Where-Object clause to refine that list to the files where the basename ends with the 'two-letters dash two-letters' sequence using regex.

Then combine that with the 'G:\OSLANGS' destination path.

```
$sourcePath  = 'G:\langpacks'
$destination = 'G:\OSLANGS'

# get a list of FileInfo objects from files with extension .cab
(Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Filter '*.cab' -Recurse) | 
    Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '.*_([a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2})$' } |  # refine the result using regex
    ForEach-Object {
        # create the target path combining the $destination and the match from the Where-Object clause 
        $targetPath = Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath $matches[1]
        # create that path is it does not already exist
        if (!(Test-Path -Path $targetPath -PathType Container)) {
            $null = New-Item -Path $targetPath -ItemType Directory
        }
        $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $targetPath -Force
    }
```

**Regex details:**

```
.              Match any single character
   *           Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
_              Match the character “_” literally
(              Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   [a-z]       Match a single character in the range between “a” and “z” (case insensitive)
      {2}      Exactly 2 times
   -           Match the character “-” literally
   [a-z]       Match a single character in the range between “a” and “z” (case insensitive)
      {2}      Exactly 2 times
)             
$              Assert position at the end of the string, or before the line break at the end of the string, if any (line feed)
```